# PHP foreach shopping cart values being overwritten

Tags: php, arrays

I have one array_push to push values through these are fine.

The question is how can i make the array more reliable so that i can have more values that will not be overwritten when they are outputted to the screen.

I currently have -

```
array_push($cart, array("id" => $_GET["itemId"]));
```

This gets my item id's then i use select on the other page. Is it possible to add more values?

On my other page i have -

```
        $cart = $_SESSION["cart"];

        echo "Your Cart Contains: <br />";

        $counter = 0;

        foreach($cart as $key){
            foreach($cart [$counter] as $item => $value){
                echo '<div id="checkoutList"><cartNum>' . $counter . '</cartNum>' . '<productNum>' . $value . '</productNum>' . '<productImg><img width="100px" height="70px" src="../Images/' . $image . '"/></productImg>' . '<productDesc>' . $desc . '</productDesc>' . '<productRemove><a href="removeItem.php?counter=' . $counter . '"><input width="200px" height="400px" type="button" value="remove" class="buttonCSS"/></a></productRemove></div><br />';
            }
            $counter++;

        }
```

The problem is that `$image`, `$desc` are being overwritten to equal the same over each product being displayed in the basket. I believe this is because they aren't being set as separate values in array so that they can differ from each other.

Is there a way that i can put them into the same array or in fact a different one which can be run with the `foreach` loop to differ each product?

Comment: Should probably mention i am relatively new to php.

Comment: Is that $image and $desc stored in DB ?

Comment: they are stored in a SQL database yes, the values are being taken fine. it's just that they are being over written when they are displayed.

Comment: okay, so solution is when you have all your product ids you do select everything else from DB for every id. I don't see in code where they getting updated. You just show the same $image var every time in your loop

Comment: Where are `$image` and `$desc` being set?

Comment: your foreach is a little bit strange. please provide an example output of `print_r($cart)` to let us show you a better way to walk through the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you render your basket, `$image` and `$desc` are, ever assigned, this can only go wrong.

Also, the fact that you have a `$counter` into a `foreach` loop that gets assigned to a `<cartNum>` tag shows that there is something really wrong here. The great benefit of `foreach` loop is that you don't need to keep track of your array index, you should use them properly.

You should have something like below, but I can't be sure without seeing your data structure.

```
$cart = $_SESSION["cart"];

echo "Your Cart Contains: <br />";

$counter = 0;

foreach($cart as $cardNum => $cartEntry){
    foreach($cartEntry as $itemNum => $item){
        $image = $item['image']; // retrieve the image
        $desc = $item['desc']; // retrieve the description

        echo '<div id="checkoutList"><cartNum>' . $itemNum . '</cartNum>' 
            . '<productNum>' . $itemNum . '</productNum>' 
            . '<productImg><img width="100px" height="70px" src="../Images/' . $image . '"/></productImg>' 
            . '<productDesc>' . $desc . '</productDesc>' 
            . '<productRemove><a href="removeItem.php?counter=' . $itemNum . '"><input width="200px" height="400px" type="button" value="remove" class="buttonCSS"/></a></productRemove></div><br />';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// assuming your cart array looks like this:
$cart = array(
    array("itemid" => 56, "count"=> 2),
    array("itemid" => 57, "count"=> 1),
    array("itemid" => 58, "count"=> 1),
    array("itemid" => 59, "count"=> 5),
    array("itemid" => 60, "count"=> 2),
);


// you should walk through the array
foreach($cart as $v) {

    // get itemid from the current array-item
    $itemid = $v['itemid'];
    $count = $v['count'];

    // get details of your item from db
    $details = class_cartitem::getDetailsById($itemid);

    // display the current item
    echo "<div>"
        . "<span>name: ".$details['name']."</span>"
        . "<span>desc: ".$details['desc']."</span>"
        . "<span>img: <img src='".$details['img']."' /></span>"
        . "<span>count: ".$count."</span>"
        . "<span>price: ".$details['price']."</span>"
        . "<span>total: ". ($details['price']*$count) ."</span>"
        . "</div>";
}
```